# outgoing mail configuration rails with MailForm gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gmail, actionmailer

I'm following [this tutorial](http://everydayrails.com/2011/09/07/rails-contact-form.html) for implementing the [mail_form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/mail_form) in my rails project. My app requires a contact form that emails the user who filled it out. The tutorial seems good, but I'm having preliminary trouble.  This:

> First things first—make sure you’ve got outgoing mail configured to your liking. I use Google-hosted mail for production, and MockSMTP or Mailcatcher in development.

Right out the gate and I'm not sure how to configure my outgoing mail.  First question: is it fine to configure both development and production via gmail? Anyway, my stab at configuration - I looked around and found something like this:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
port:                 587,
domain:               'example.com',
user_name:            '<username>',
password:             '<password>',
authentication:       'plain',
enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

which I then placed in my `config/environments/development.rb.

From the rails console I made a new ContactForm and utilized MailForm to deliver it.  This appeared to be successful within the console, but did not actually email the target address.  I'm sure I'm just misunderstanding the differences between development and production configuration, but how can I see if this is working in development outside of the console, and will continue to work in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue, which came from the controller.

Try something like this:

**contacts_conroller.rb**

```
    class ContactsController < ApplicationController 

    def new
    @contact = Contact.new
    if 
    Contact.new(params[:contact]).deliver
    redirect_to '/contacts/thanks', :alert => ["Yeah!"]
    end
   else

   end


   def create
@contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    if 
   @contact.valid?
@contact.deliver
   end
   else 
  render :new
  end

  end
```